# Django Bootstrap modal is giving an error

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am using jQuery script excecuted on an `on("click")` event to do following:

1. ajax call to Django url / view that populates a 'modal template'.
2. modal template's HTML is then appended to an empty modal div.
3. ajax `success` event then does `show()` modal div.

Everything appears to work successfully eg I get the modal to show, with populated modal template content, but I am also getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation selector-engine.js:22 
at Object.findOne (selector-engine.js:22)
at De._showElement (modal.js:221)
at modal.js:143
at b (index.js:242)
at backdrop.js:53
at b (index.js:242)
at v (index.js:248)
at ke._emulateAnimation (backdrop.js:125)
at ke.show (backdrop.js:52)
at De._showBackdrop (modal.js:328)
```

Any ideas what is happening here?

Using Bootstrap 5, jquery-3.6

Empty modal div:

```
<div id="modal-div"></div>
```

Script:

```
var modalDiv = $("#modal-div");
$(".open-modal").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
        success: function(data) {
            modalDiv.html(data);
            $("#photo-modal").modal('show');
        },
    });
});
```

Edit to add: The script and empty modal div are both in the Django "base.html" file.

Modal template HTML:

```
<div id="photo-modal" class="modal-container">

    <p>{{ photo.id }}</p>

</div>
```

Comment: The script and empty modal div are both in the Django "base.html" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to modify `<div id="modal-div"></div>` so it was `<div class="modal" id="modal-div"></div>`